# Extrema on (compact) vinculum

Tags: optimization, lagrange-multiplier

My textbook ask to find the extrema of $f(x,y) = 2x^2+y^2$ on $x^4-x^2+y^2-5=0$. It uses the lagrangian multipliers to find critic points.. Then it computes the function on these points then says "this is the maximum, this is the minimum".

I can't understand: they could be saddle points! I believe that it is using the weierstrass theorem for compact sets.. In this case the vinculum is a compact set, so it must have minimum and maximum! Is my conclusion correct? In general, how can you be sure that the vinculum is compact?

Edit:
my question was general: suppose it is not easy to do that substition.. If you want to use multipliers you have to know that maximum/min points exist.. So compact vinculum could be good! Bit how do you recognize it

Comment: This particular case is easy, because $f(x,y)=-x^4+3x^2+5$, so we do not need Lagrange multipliers and you can see directly from the derivative that $x=\pm\sqrt{\frac{3}{2}}$ are maxima and $x=0$ a minimum. Of course $x=0,y=\pm\sqrt5$ is only a local minimum and the others local maxima. So you still have to check that $y=0$ gives a value which lies between them. Weierstrass only guarantees maximum and minimum values. They could still lie on the boundary.

Comment: @almagest why y=0? Where does it come from? However my question was more general: suppose it is not easy to do that substition.. If you want to use multipliers you have to know that maximum/min points exist.. So compact vinculum could be good! Bit how do you recognize it?

Comment: If $|x|$ is too large, then the constraint would make $y^2<0$, which is impossible. The condition $y\ge0$ is what determines the range of possible $x$. In general it is not easy to recognize the type of stationary point for functions on $\mathbb{R^2}$.

Comment: @almagest but aren't y=0 points included in the parametrized function? When did I neglected it in the substition?

Comment: @almagest edit: sorry..I got it, you're right!